# How to disable the back button when the alert box is on the screen

Tags: android, dialog

I used onKeyDown function in the activity.....but when back button
button is clicked it first cancels the dialog box and goes to our
activity...I want both either both activity and dialog box closed when
clicking the back button or disable the back button when the dialog
box is shown...

can any one suggest any solutions for this....

Thanks in advance,

---

**Update**

Hello Thanks for your answer.
The `progressDialog` with `.setCancelable(false);` is working fine.

But here I want different thing. 
When the progress dialog is running then i will press the BACK key and i want to show an alert dialog so that the user can notify that the progress is running.

Is there any solution about it?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 57):

Did you  try setting its `setCancelable()` property to false

Something like this

```
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: - this works with AlertDialog as well...just in case anyone needs to know.

Answer (score 2):

May be this will help in your case:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // Show your Alert Box here
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

The issue was long back. I will try if get time.

Comment: just to be late than never :)

Answer (score 0):

I just want to improve @MoJo answer

```
alertDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
               //Your handler   


               return false;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally a cleaner solution was to finish the LoginActivity before starting the intent instead of setting Flags in the bundle of the new activity or overriding any methods. Try something like this below where Login is your login activity and Home is the first activity after successfully login in the user.

```
finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

"I want both either both activity and dialog box closed"

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    finish();
    return true;
  }
});
```

"or disable the back button when the dialog box is shown" This can block going back from dialog. When creating it dynamically, add:

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Returning true is preventing this dialog from closing, and it cannot be closed by clicking back. Also I suggest adding:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

What will prevent user from dismissing dialog by clicking outside of it.